# Extracting specific delimited fields using sed

Tags: unix, sed

Learning sed and patterns.

I have lines of input that look like this:

```
1000001,P00069042,F,0-17,10,A,2,0,3,,,8370
1000001,P00248942,F,0-17,10,A,2,0,1,6,14,15200
1000001,P00087842,F,0-17,10,A,2,0,12,,,1422
1000001,P00085442,F,0-17,10,A,2,0,12,14,,1057
1000002,P00285442,M,55+,16,C,4+,0,8,,,7969
1000003,P00193542,M,26-35,15,A,3,0,1,2,,15227
```

I need to extract the first, second, and last fields. The output for the first line would be something like

```
1000001 P00069042 8370
```

I have tried `sed -n 's/,.*,.*,/ /p'` but it only returns the first and last fields. 
I have also tried `sed -n 's/\([^,]*,[^,]*,\).*,/ /p'` but it only returns the last field.

My approach is to delete everything between the second comma and the last comma, but I don't know how to specify the second comma.

I'm aware this can be done with cut or awk, but I'm trying to figure out sed.

Comment: While it may just be an intellectual exercise, it's the wrong tool for the problem. As you say, cut(1) or awk(1) would be simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sed](/questions/tagged/sed) is great for unstructured/raw stream data -- this isn't one of those.
Nonetheless, the trick to using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) to pick out "fields" is to:

1. Create a regex that matches the **whole** line
2. Use capture groups `\(..\)` to pick out the parts you want to save
3. Use the `[^<c>]*<c>` idiom to enforce non-greedy behavior where needed (`<c>` is any char)
4. Replace the entire line using back-references from the capture groups you saved

---

```
$ echo 1000001,P00069042,F,0-17,10,A,2,0,3,,,8370 |\
    sed 's/^\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),.*,\(.*\)$/\1 \2 \3/'
1000001 P00069042 8370
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What does the '$' do?

Comment: `^` and `$` are [start and end-of-line anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).  Unfortunately `^` is over-loaded to have a completely different meaning of negation when the first char inside a character class, as in `[^ ]`